# Can't start Python, import error

Tags: python, environment-variables, anaconda

Yesterday I installed the mysql connector package, today I can't start python anymore. Anacona won't start nor directly Python 3.6. The Anaconda prompt delivered:

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.17134.48]
(c) 2018 Microsoft Corporation. Alle Rechte vorbehalten.

C:\Users\ric22>python.exe -m idlelib.idle
Error processing line 1 of C:\Users\ric22\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\protobuf-3.5.2.post1-py3.6-nspkg.pth:
Failed to import the site module
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\ric22\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site.py", line 168, in addpackage
    exec(line)
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "D:\Programme\Anaconda\pkgs\sqlalchemy-1.1.13-py36h5948d12_0\Lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\dialects\mysql\types.py", line 9, in <module>
    from ... import exc, util
ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\ric22\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site.py", line 544, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:\Users\ric22\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site.py", line 531, in main
    known_paths = addsitepackages(known_paths)
  File "C:\Users\ric22\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site.py", line 328, in addsitepackages
    addsitedir(sitedir, known_paths)
  File "C:\Users\ric22\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site.py", line 207, in addsitedir
    addpackage(sitedir, name, known_paths)
  File "C:\Users\ric22\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site.py", line 178, in addpackage
    import traceback
  File "C:\Users\ric22\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\traceback.py", line 5, in <module>
    import linecache
  File "C:\Users\ric22\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\linecache.py", line 8, in <module>
    import functools
  File "C:\Users\ric22\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\functools.py", line 22, in <module>
    from types import MappingProxyType
  File "D:\Programme\Anaconda\pkgs\sqlalchemy-1.1.13-py36h5948d12_0\Lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\dialects\mysql\types.py", line 9, in <module>
    from ... import exc, util
ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package
```

Does anyone have an idea how to make Python run again? Thanks in Advance

Ric

Comment: It looks like you are missing the environment variable `PYTHONPATH`, which is supposed to contain a delimited list of paths where python looks up its dependencies, much like `CLASSPATH` in Java or `PATH` for executables in pretty much any OS. E.g. `D:\Programme\Anaconda\pkgs\` should be in PYTHONPATH

Answer (score 0):

Thanks amphibient,

I had set this environment variable 'cause I couldn't make mysql package work on Spyder:
D:\Programme\Anaconda\pkgs\sqlalchemy-1.1.13-py36h5948d12_0\Lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\dialects\mysql\types.py
(Now I see .py is obviously no folder ;))
This messed everything up. I removed it and installed the package with
*conda install mysql-connector-python* typed into conda path.
Now everything works.